# Need help in 2 proving hypercube problems

Tags: graph-theory

**а)** Let's have three vertices in B. Prove that two of them are at a distance not greater than $2n\over3$

**b)** Specify four vertices in $B_{3k}$, k > 0, such that each two of them are at a distance of 2k.

Answer (score 2):

a) Denote given vertices by $x=(x_1,\dots, x_n)$, $y=(y_1,\dots, y_n)$, and  $z=(z_1,\dots, z_n)$. For each coordinate $i$ from $1$ to $n$ there exist two distinct vertices $a(i), b(i)\in\{x,y,z\}$ such that $a(i)=b(i)$. So there exists two distinct vertices $a, b\in\{x,y,z\}$ such that $\{a,b\}=\{a(i),b(i)\}$ for at least $n/3$ distinct $i$’s. Then the distance between $a$ and $b$ is not greater than $n-\frac n3=\frac {2n}3$.

b) I provide an answer for $k=4$, for general $k$ the pattern is the same:

```
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```